# How do I make a line graph without using ggplot in r?

Tags: r, graph, time-series, rows, linegraph

I have this dataset:

at the beginning I had,

```
Date      Action  Daily.Contact
1/1/2012  All        4
1/1/2012  Email      2
1/1/2012  Text       1
2/2/2012  Phone Call 1
2/2/2012  All        7
2/2/2012  Email      2
2/2/2012  Text       2
2/2/2012  Phone Call 2
3/3/2012  All        4
3/3/2012  Email      2
3/3/2012  Text       1
3/3/2012  Phone Call 1
4/3/2012  All        9
4/3/2012  Email      4
4/3/2012  Text       4
4/3/2012  Phone Call 1
```

After some data manipulation I ended up with:

```
Date      All Email Text Phone Call
1/1/2012  4   2     1     1
2/2/2012  7   2     2     3
3/3/2012  4   2     1     1
4/4/2012  9   3     4     2
```

How do I create a line graph showing 3 lines for Email, Text, Phone call?

So far I have:

```
plot(as.Date(df$Date), df$Daily.Contact, 
 type = 'l', lwd = 2, xlab = "Date", ylab = "Daily.Contact")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

## Data

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "Date      All Email Text 'Phone Call'
1/1/2012  4   2     1     1
2/2/2012  7   2     2     3
3/3/2012  4   2     1     1
4/4/2012  9   3     4     2", header = T) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Check min, max of `Daily Contact` for `ylim`

```
max(df[,3:5])
[1] 4
min(df[,3:5])
[1] 1
```

Then,

```
plot(df$Date, df$Email, type = "l", lwd = 2, xlab = "Date", ylab = "Daily Contact", col = "red", ylim = c(1,4))
lines(df$Date, df$Text,  lwd = 2, col = "steelblue")
lines(df$Date, df$Phone.Call,  lwd = 2, col = "brown")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `matplot`: Plots a matrix of points

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

matplot(df$Date, df[-1], type = 'l', lwd = 2, xlab = 'Date', ylab = 'Daily Contact')
```

[image]